# Entity Framework Core doesn't check for entity existence when hitting an api endpoint

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When hitting an API endpoint to insert an entity, EF adds any populated Navigation Properties to their appropriate tables. This is great except when that Entity already exists whereupon it throws a duplicate record error.

I am creating a database of words for another language and these words have relationships. Let's say I have a Noun class, a Meaning class, a linking NounMeaning class, and an api controller to add a noun.

```
    public class Noun
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public List<NounMeaning> NounMeanings { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Meaning
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public List<NounMeaning> NounMeanings { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class NounMeaning
    {
        public int NounId { get; set; }
        public int MeaningId { get; set; }

        public Noun Noun { get; set; }
        public Meaning Meaning { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class LanguageContext : DbContext
    {
        public LanguageContext(DbContextOptions<LanguageContext> options)
           : base(options)
        { }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<NounMeaning>().HasKey(nm => new { mm.NounId, nm.MeaningId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Meaning>().HasIndex(m => m.Value).IsUnique();
        }

        public DbSet<Noun> Nouns { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Meaning> Meanings { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostNoun([FromBody] Noun noun)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            _context.Nouns.Add(noun);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

```
{
    "Value": "Word",
    "NounMeanings": [
        { 
            "Meaning":  {
                "Value": "boy"
            } 
        }
    ]
}
```

If I hit the endpoint with the above JSON, the first time I get a valid response back. The noun is added to the Nouns table, along with the meaning in the Meanings table and the linking table, NounMeanings is correctly added to.

If I hit the endpoint again only changing the Noun Value in the JSON, say with a value of Word2, what I would expect to happen is the Noun getting added to the Nouns Table, the Meanings Table remaining unchanged as the meaning already exists, and the NounMeanings table to have another row inserted (2, 1 for the columns for eg).

Instead an error is returned saying there would be duplication in the Meanings table as it tries to enter the meaning again (this is the error message from Postman):

```
<h2 class="stackerror">SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object
                        &#x27;dbo.Meanings&#x27; with unique index &#x27;IX_Meanings_Value&#x27;. The duplicate key
                        value is (boy).&#xD;&#xA;The statement has been terminated.</h2>
                    <ul>
```

I would have expected EF to be smart enough to check for the meaning existence and before adding the record.

Instead I have to add the following logic to get it to pass correctly (please note, the code below was a test to see if it worked hence the hard coded indexes).

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostNoun([FromBody] Noun noun)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            Meaning meaning = _context.Meanings.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Value == noun.NounMeanings[0].Meaning.Value);

            if(meaning != null)
            {
                noun.NounMeanings = new List<NounMeaning>();
                noun.NounMeanings.Add(new NounMeaning { Meaning = meaning });
            }

            _context.Nouns.Add(noun);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This isn't great as it requires more time for these checks (many more as the actual db is more complicated) and requires an extra DB call.

I don't remember having to do this in EF Framework but it has been a very long time since I wrote a DB from scratch so maybe I am missing something.

Thanks for any help. This has been frustrating me all weekend.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a description of what keys and indices you have in the database and in the EDMX file or model configuration. If possible add the full database table description as a `CREATE TABLE` statement. Also include the full complete error message you get.

Comment: I have added the Context and ModelBuilder used to build the db as this is an EF Core Code First Solution. I have also included the error message as received in postman from where the request was sent.

Comment: When a table has a primary key you cannot put more than on item with same key.  So need to replace current value with new value.  Or create two tables.  One with the unique keys and second with values.  Then join two tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework has never had the behavior you're expecting - the DbSet.Add method is only intended to be used for inserting records. You're supposed to attach an entity, if you're trying to update an existing record. This is for EF6, but the logic applies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state

This falls under "opinion," rather than cold, hard fact, but it's generally a bad idea to use data models (the classes which model your database tables) as view models (the classes that are used to bind data in higher levels, such as the UI) - it's rare (in my experience) that you need the same object graph in the UI as your data source requires.

For example, you've shown this as your database model:

```
public class Noun
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public List<NounMeaning> NounMeanings { get; set; }
}

public class Meaning
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public List<NounMeaning> NounMeanings { get; set; }
}

public class NounMeaning
{
    public int NounId { get; set; }
    public int MeaningId { get; set; }

    public Noun Noun { get; set; }
    public Meaning Meaning { get; set; }
}
```

That `NounMeaning` class would exist as a database table, so that you could have a many-to-many join. In full framework EF (EF6 and less), you wouldn't actually need that as a data model class - it was smart enough to make the join. EF Core requires that join table (the EF Core team has reasons why this is the case, but you'd have to dig through the issues on the Guthub project to find them), but that doesn't mean your application layer needs to deal with that model. I'd expect something like this:

```
public class Noun
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public List<Meaning> Meanings { get; set; }
}

public class Meaning
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public List<Noun> Nouns { get; set; }
}
```

This makes **logical** sense - a Noun has multiple Meanings, and a Meaning can be described by multiple Nouns. A developer might find that model easier to deal with at the application level, so you'd create DTO (data-transfer object) classes as noted above. You could also then add any helper methods that made sense, without polluting your data models.

There's actually an MSDN / MS Docs article that discusses this, as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5

Comment: So I have to do the logic myself in that case? Also, could you expand on your second paragraph and how I might improve it?

Comment: Yes. It may seem like EF should be "smarter," but the logic on what constitutes an "Add" versus an "Insert" isn't a one-size-fits-all proposition.

Comment: I added a bit to the answer - let me know if that helps.

Comment: That makes sense. Those DTO objects are what I would hit the endpoint with, then use any helper methods to map them to the Data Models and also use helpers/repos to do data checks (such as checking if the meaning already exists etc). Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: Correct. Granted, in a simple application, it might make more sense to just use the data models, but using DTOs gives you more control over what data is passed around.